# User set default settings for a Block in Site Editor

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

For a block I want the user to be able to set a couple of *defaults for each newly generated block*, think e.g colors and other attributes. Then every time a new block is created on the website, the defaults should be loaded. Each block can then be customized from the sidebar if needed (`<InspectorControls>)`. For example the user sets text color to red, but then occasionally can choose another color.

So far I created a custom settings page for the WordPress plugin and then I load these defaults into the block when it gets registered. Feels like a hack, but works.

The new block themes now have a **Site Editor** and somewhere in there it is also possible to set the default styles of a block widget.

How can I access this menu and add items similar to the Sidebar of each specific block? Would be great to be able to replicate all the `<InspectorControls>` of the Sidebar as Defaults. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way to get your block’s settings to show up in the Global Styles (so their defaults can be set) is by using the [Supports API](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-supports/). It’s automatic if your block’s settings are implemented via Supports.

Here it is [from the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/explanations/architecture/styles/#current-limitations-of-the-global-styles-api):

> The global styles UI in the site editor has a screen for per-block styles. The list of blocks is generated dynamically using the block supports from the block.json of blocks. If a block wants to be listed there, it needs to use the block supports mechanism.

Comment: I have to admit, i have difficulty understanding what to do exactly. If that is the way it should be done, is there a tutorial or practical example somewhere? Shouldn't be something really unusual to have user defined defaults.

Comment: [Video tutorial](https://youtu.be/WTvsvJ3SaaM?si=ucbfB6DDu9PcQ24q&t=236) (starting at the part about color since that was a property you mentioned). [Text tutorial](https://fullstackdigital.io/blog/adding-options-to-custom-blocks-with-block-supports-block-creator-02/). Once a block is using supports for its settings then it shows up in the Global Styles so that users can define the defaults.